# In Google Sheets, How to use a function to split columns and rows at the same time?

Tags: google-sheets

I succeed when there was only one row.

```
=SPLIT("aaa|bbb|ccc", "|", false)
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb | ccc |

And I succeeded when there was only one column.

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT("aaa\nbbb\nccc", "\n", false))
```

| A |
| --- |
| aaa |
| bbb |
| ccc |

But, what to do when the original data looks like this?

```
="aaa|bbb|ccc\nddd|eee|fff\nggg|hhh|iii"
```

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | bbb | ccc |
| ddd | eee | fff |
| ggg | hhh | iii |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a formula that should work for you:

`=arrayformula(split(transpose(split("aaa|bbb|ccc\nddd|eee|fff\nggg|hhh|iii", "\n")), "|"))`

[image: ex]

It splits columns first, and then rows.

Please let me know if you have any issues with this